# Pyspark aggregate columns when pivoting seperate colums

Tags: pyspark, pivot, aggregate, group

If i have e.g. a table of driving data by month

| month | user | activity | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | driving | 2 |
| Jan | 1 | stopped | 5 |
| Jan | 2 | driving | 1 |
| Jan | 2 | stopped | 0 |

I want to count the distinct users per month and sum the duration per activity and total activity per month. The resulting table could look like this

| month | distinctUsers | drivingHours | stoppedHours | totalActivity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 2 | 3 | 5 | 8 |
| Feb | 14 | 15 | 32 | 47 |

I can get a table of the activity by

`df.groupBy('month').pivot('activity').sum('duration')`

and i can get a table of the distinct and total sum of duration by

`df.groupBy('month').agg(F.countDistinct('user'),F.sum('duration'))`

Is there any way to do an aggregate during a pivot or should i just join my two current tables?

Comment: Just join the two dataframes